# DNS client not getting hosts resolved. Configuration is correct

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a machine that was working fine, after some attempts to configure a link redundancy on my network the machine with the following configuration stopped resolving DNS names.

```
IP:      192.168.1.7
Mask:    255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.254
DNS:     8.8.8.8
```

The machine that I'm in right now has the same configuration, apart form the IP, and is working fine.

The problematic machine is a Windows Server R2

EDIT:

I got two ISPs, one on .1.1 and another no .1.254. Everything was fine, than I decided to setup a the redundancy for .1.7

I tried to setup the server with two gateways, .1.1 with metric 1 and .1.254 with metric 10. 
After I did that, ISP 1 went down and the hole town is without internet.
ISP 2 is still working, I'm using it write now. But the configuration that I1m using doesn't work on my .1.7 server.

EDIT 2:

I've changed the Ip from 192.168.1.7 to 192.168.1.251, the gateway is 192.168.1.251 and the DNS server 177.104.240.1 and
177.104.240.1

The server can ping any ip on the internet, but wont get resolved names.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup -debug google.com 177.104.240.1
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  177.104.240.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
    timeout (2 secs)
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
timeout (2 secs)
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

Answer (score 0):

1) are you sure ip information is correct?  most home devices have 1.1 as the default gateway not 1.254

2) 8.8.8.8 is google. you should use your isp provided nameservers, as the first time you go out to the internet, they may rewrite dns to take you to a terms of service page.  then, once you accect, they allow outcgoing tcp/80 tcp/443 on layer 3/4 firewalll level..... they is similmlr to active portal (which works awesome on pfsense btw).... there are exceptions to this.  ive heard you can still get some udp ports thru (ie set up ipsec tunnel) but never done that. good luck doing *that* with pfsense :)

EDIT:

it sounds lke you can get out to internet just fine...... it may be that all of your dns requests to google have made them block you. ------>  use your isp provided dns servers and that should fix it

EDIT:

>
lamp@oort ~ $ whois 8.8.8.8|grep -i name
NetName:        LVLT-ORG-8-8
OrgName:        Level 3 Communications, Inc.
OrgAbuseName:   Abuse POC LVLT
OrgNOCName:   NOC Support
OrgTechName:   ipaddressing
NetName:        LVLT-GOOGL-1-8-8-8
OrgName:        Google Incorporated
OrgAbuseName:   Google Inc
OrgTechName:   Network Engineering Corp
OrgAbuseName:   Network Engineering Corp

Comment: I've tried other DNS servers, they work on every machine but not on the one with IP .7. On that machine can get out through gateway .254

Comment: is there another device on your lan with .7?  try changing ip's on the host, ethernet cables, and switchport server is connected to.   verify laver 2 is good, and then move to layer 3.   check fw/gameway to make sure .7 is not firewalled or otherwise in use

Comment: I'll try, but everything was just fine. Check my edit.